# Implementing BeautifulSoup to Android Studio with chaquopy

Tags: python, android, beautifulsoup, chaquopy

I'm currently making a web scraping app using Android Studio with BeautifulSoup. How do I implement

> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

into Android Studio as I would in Python?

My build.gradle is

```
python {
        buildPython "C:/Python38/python.exe"
        pip{
            install "bs4"
            install "beautifulsoup4"
            install "requests"
        }
    }
```

and my imports in Python is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
```

I used

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
```

in the Python file and it seemed to do the job.

Comment: To use lxml, you can add "lxml" to your `pip install` list.